# Tap gesture on stacked images

Tags: ios, image, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

i want to show up images in my view and add the tap gesture to do some stuff. 
My code looks like this for the image creation

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    UIImageView *imageToMove =
    [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1.png"]];
    imageToMove.frame = CGRectMake(((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 1024, ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 768 , 95, 95);
    [imageToMove setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [imageToMove addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [self.view addSubview:imageToMove];

}
```

and this simple function to get some feedback when a image is tapped

```
- (void)tapDetected {
    NSLog(@"single Tap on imageview");

}
```

My Problem is, only one (IMHO the last one added) image is touchable. The other images "behind" can't be accessed.

Is there a possibility to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you would like to do when tapping on stacked images (I mean, the natural thing would be that the image you touch can move, and this is should be accomplished by your code); in any case, try with:

```
 singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

This will make your gesture recognizers not cancel the tap they handle, so the holding view will also receive the events. If this does not help, have a look at the [`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:) and specifically at the method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)otherGestureRecognizer
```

which should allow to fine-control how your gesture recognizers co-exist.

Comment: At the end i want to remove the image when its tapped. But at the moment i would have to tap the images in the order they were created.

Comment: well, as I said, it should work "out-of-the-box"; if you have to images partially overlapping, if you tap the visible portion of the image that is below the other, then this image will receive the tap.  Of course you will only be able to tap partially covered images, not fully covered images...